# match object in javascript and assign value

Tags: javascript, typescript

as you can see if you check the data source it has a key isEdit and it has a boolean value.
We compare dataSouce value to tempValues as you can see the column value from data source matches the
keys on the tempValues. After we compare we check if the value from the datasource which is isEdit is true or fals

if the value of isEdit is true get value from tempValues.dealIdleDetailsForFinanceDto so for example NVB isEdit value is true so the nvb value from
tempValues.dealIdleDetailsForFinanceDto is 99 else it is 20

Check value of final output.

Please see final output for comparison. Thanks.

#data 1

```
dataSouce = [
    {
        "name": "NVB",
        "value": 0,
        "financeValue": 0,
        "column": "nvb",
        "isEdit": true
    },
    {
        "name": "ROU",
        "value": 0,
        "financeValue": 0,
        "column": "rou",
        "isEdit": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Net Present Value",
        "value": 0,
        "financeValue": 0,
        "column": "netPresentValue",
        "isEdit": false
    },
]
```

#tempValues

```
tempValues = {
    "transactionId": 20,
    "nvb": 20,
    "rou": 100,
    "netPresentValue": 50,
     "dealIdleDetailsForFinanceDto": {
        "nvb": 99,
        "rou": 4,
        "netPresentValue": 88,
    }
}
```

#Sample Final Output

```
[
  {
    "name": "NVB",
    "value": 99,
    "financeValue": 20,
    "column": "nvb",
    "isEdit": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ROU",
    "value": 100,
    "financeValue": 100,
    "column": "rou",
    "isEdit": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Net Present Value",
    "value": 88,
    "financeValue": 50,
    "column": "netPresentValue",
    "isEdit": true
  }
]
```

#sample code

```
        const finalOutput = dataSource.map(item => {
  // Look up the value in tempValues using the column property of the object

  if(item.isEdit) {
    
  }

  const financeValue = tempValues[item.column];
  
  // Return a new object with the updated value property
  return {
    ...item,
    financeValue, 
  };
});
```

Comment: In the example, should `dataSouce[2].isEdit` be `true`?

Comment: No , some values are true and some values are false

Comment: In which case, how does the final output have `isEdit: true` for this object, and why does it get the value from the property in `tempValues.dealIdleDetailsForFinanceDto`?

Comment: just please based it on the final ouput Sir and you will understand

Comment: Sorry, there seems to be an inconsistency between the data and the description. Happy to help, but if the description doesn't line up with the data that is very difficult.

Comment: as you can see if you check the data source it has a key isEdit and it has a boolean value.
We compare dataSouce value to tempValues as you can see the column value from data source matches the
keys on the tempValues. After we compare we check if the value from the datasource which is isEdit is true or fals

if the value of isEdit is true get value from tempValues.dealIdleDetailsForFinanceDto so for example NVB isEdit value is true so the nvb value from
tempValues.dealIdleDetailsForFinanceDto is 99 else it is 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `dataSouce[2].isEdit = true`, and that this is a typo in the question, then the following code snippet should help.

```js
dataSource = [
    {
        "name": "NVB",
        "value": 0,
        "financeValue": 0,
        "column": "nvb",
        "isEdit": true
    },
    {
        "name": "ROU",
        "value": 0,
        "financeValue": 0,
        "column": "rou",
        "isEdit": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Net Present Value",
        "value": 0,
        "financeValue": 0,
        "column": "netPresentValue",
        "isEdit": true
    },
];

tempValues = {
    "transactionId": 20,
    "nvb": 20,
    "rou": 100,
    "netPresentValue": 50,
     "dealIdleDetailsForFinanceDto": {
        "nvb": 99,
        "rou": 4,
        "netPresentValue": 88,
    }
};

const finalOutput = dataSource.map(item => {
  const tempValue = tempValues[item.column];
  const dealIdleDetailsValue = tempValues.dealIdleDetailsForFinanceDto[item.column];
  return {
    ...item,
    financeValue: tempValue,
    value: item.isEdit ? dealIdleDetailsValue : tempValue
  }
});

console.log(finalOutput);
```

Comment: Did this answer solve the problem? If so, please mark it as accepted or let me know where it fails to help you.